# Quartz Composer: switch video inputs with mouse

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, movie, quartz-composer

Scenario: two Quicktime movie inputs, one plays on loop unless user clicks left mouse button, in which case second movie plays until the end, then first movie plays.

Logically I can see it using a conditional.  If number = 1, loop movie 1.  If mouse click, number = 2, movie 2 plays.  At end of play, number = 1, loop movie 1.

What I can't figure out is how to increase a number and have it stick without the left mouse being held down, and how to switch the movie back after the second one plays.

In my head, I'd have it wouldn't matter that the number increases to 2 for an instant, because at that point the conditional will instantly jump to number 2.  But after number 2 plays, how do I get movie one to play?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it as follows: feed movie A and movie B into inputs 0 and 1 of a multiplexer patch, then feed the left click output from the mouse control patch to the multiplexer's index, and Quartz will convert the boolean mouse click (0 or 1) to an index (0 or 1) telling the multiplexer to output one or the other of your videos, depending on the stat of the users mouse. The complete thing would look like this:

[image: QC Code]

Comment: @ThinkingSTiff, how would you recommend I insert Quartz Composer Code? It's a visual media file of several megabytes, so I wasn't sure what to do...